# Multiple apps based on the same code base fails biometric authentication on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, biometrics, localauthentication

I have multiple apps based on the same code base. And we are having features called biometric authentication on the app when the app is opened.

When I have the **App-1** installed and then installing any other apps of mine like the **App-2** app my biometric stops for the **App-1** app and works for the **App-2**. Similarly, if I am installing the other app of mine biometric like **App-3** it shifts to a newly installed app and stops for the rest of the app like App-1 and App-2.

And if I delete the newly installed app the biometric starts working only for the latest one from the list of apps installed.

It's like it will work for one app which is last installed on my device. Rest other biometric is not working.

Steps 1

App-1 -> Installed

App-2 -> Installed

App-3 -> Installed

If all three 3 installed works for the latest installed i.e  App-3

Step 2

App-1 -> Installed

App-2 -> Installed

App-3 -> Deleted

Now deleted App-3 biometric start working for App-2

**It's happening on iOS devices.**

Any anyone faces this plz help.

**App Installed from Test Flight:** https://photos.app.goo.gl/CMQPYEbd76ghkM9w8

**Problem Facing on iOS Device**
https://photos.app.goo.gl/nEUfpR6UMfzw4E8h8

**On Simulator Works Fine**
https://photos.app.goo.gl/Xq4bVYAFquTgj6cf9